# what is the value of $x$ in this logarithmic question?

Tags: logarithms

What is the value of $x$:

\begin{equation}
x^{\log_5 x} >5
\end{equation}

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then take $\log_5$ on both sides and see.

Comment: Any value of x greater than 5

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: For example: If $x=\frac1{25}$, then $$(\frac{1}{25})^{-2}=25^2>2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^{\log_5x}>5$$
Let $f(x)=x^{\log_5x}-5$ for $x>0$. Find $x$ such that $f(x)=0$
$$\color{red}{\log_5}x^{\log_5x}=\color{red}{\log_5}5$$
$$\log_5x\cdot \log_5x=1$$
$$(\log_5x)^2=1$$
$$\log_5x=\pm1$$
$x=5$ or $x=\frac15$

Answer: $x\in (0;\frac15)\cup(5;+\infty)$

Comment: Are you sure what if I take x as 6

Comment: Close: bring back the equality, then you need $x > 5$ OR $x < 1/5$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $0\lt a\lt b$ if and only if $\log_5a\lt\log_5b$, and thus

$$\begin{align}
5\lt x^{\log_5x}&\iff\log_55\lt\log_5(x^{\log_5x})\\
&\iff1\lt(\log_5x)^2\\
&\iff1\lt\log_5x\quad\text{or}\quad\log_5x\lt-1\\
&\iff5\lt x\quad\text{or}\quad 0\lt x\lt5^{-1}
\end{align}$$

Remark:  This is essentially the same solution as in Roman83's answer, just presented in a style that makes the logical connections explcit.